# Why does an Arraylist throw ConcurrentModificationexception even when a copy is made, but CopyOnWriteArrayList doesn't?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game where every time the user touches the screen, a bullet gets added to the list. And periodically, I am iterating over that list to do something.

To avoid ConcurrentModificationexception, I made a copy of the list first and then iterated over it.

```
List<Bullet> temp = bullets; // main list is bullets
for (Bullet b : temp) {
  // do something
}
```

But this still ended up throwing a ConcurrentModificationexception some of the time. But when I copied the array with CopyOnWriteArrayList, this didn't happen.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Bullet> temp1 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Bullet>(bullets);
```

Why does this work instead? The information I found online talks about modifying a list directly while iterating over it, but I was already making a copy of the list before. So why does making a copy of the list through ArrayList not work, but making a copy through CopyOnWriteArrayList does?

Comment: See answer from polo-language below. However, even if you make a copy and iterate over that you can still get the same error because the list can be modified while you are making the copy. It is just less likely to happen as the copy gets created very quickly.

Comment: @ewramner Is this because to copy the list, Java still iterates over it first? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: Yes, exactly. To be safe the original list either needs to be protected with synchronization or locks or it needs to be of the copy-on-write kind that doesn't update the list in-place. For most applications Collections.synchronizedList(original) that wraps the list and makes all methods synchronized works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` is not a copy of the list `bullets`, it is a copy of the *reference* to `bullets`. So `temp` and `bullets` point to the same `List` and hence, any modification made through one reference is visible via the other reference. What you really need is a new `List` that contains the same elements as the original. One way to make a shallow `List` copy is to use the copy constructor for `ArrayList` like so:

```java
List<Bullet> temp = new ArrayList<>(bullets);
```

This copies each `Bullet` reference from `bullets` into a new `List`, which is then independent of the original.
That's just what you're doing with the `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which is (one of the reasons) it is more resilient to concurrent modification.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both ArrayList and CopyOnWriteArrayList implements the Iterable,

The ArrayList implemetation of Iterable, next() method maintains modcount/cursor with size internal array, so change on the original list will throw ConcurrentModificationException and also ArrayList support remove() of Iterable because it is safely modifies the cursor.

CopyOnWriteArrayList implemetation of Iterable, next() method only reads internal array elements and even not support remove() of Iterable.